# Managing python dependecies for installing other packages

Tags: python-packaging, package-management

Python packages can be installed via system packages managers (*e.g.*, `apt`) or through dedicated managers (*e.g.*, `pip`). Consider installing a system package that depends on python packages. **What is the best practice on managing python dependencies of system packages?** As I see it, there are two possibilities:

- The manager (`apt`-like) simply installs what it needs, which may cause python package duplication, *e.g.*, the user already installed say `numpy` through `pip` which `apt` does not detect and will also install `numpy`, which may cause version conflicts among other issues;
- The manager (`apt`-like) has to check if the dependency packages were installed by some other manager, which may cause version issues later on if an `apt` package requires updated versions of python packages, which will not be handled by `apt`.

Comment: the first one is both true and best practice, for the reasons you are listing in the second. I don't have much more to say though, so this is hardly an answer.

Comment: note that if a python package is not installed through pip, it will usually be called e.g. [`python-numpy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-numpy&searchon=names) to avoid name clashes.